# Joint learning using Perceptron in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

How can I do a joint learning using Scikit-learn? 
I have two classifiers using two different feature-set and I can train them separately. But I want to train them together (they using same data). How can I do that using Perceptron in scikit-learn?

Comment: You mean, train them concurrently using the different features? Even if they train on the same starting dataset, the data they "see" will be different when choosing different features, and they have to learn a different set of weights. If you have multiple cores, why not just run simultaneously two copies of your Python script, one for each different feature set?

Comment: @machielo By joint learning I didn't meant parallel. I meant jointly, which means both classifiers can see the answer of of the other one and change the weight accordingly

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry :)

Comment: Do you mean ensemble methods or any data fusion technique?

Comment: @maheshakya no, each classifier here would be used on it's own, just the training process will be don jointly

Comment: It is still not clear from the question what you mean by "joint learning". Can you write down the model or give a reference?

Comment: @AndreasMueller, sure there are tons of paper out there, for example this: "A Joint Model for Semantic Role Labeling"
I did implement my own code but it would be great if I could use scikit-learn toolkit

Comment: This kind of model will be applied to solve both problems together, so not only the training will be jointly, also the prediction will be, contrary to what you said above. This would be a multi-label prediction if you just have two classification tasks. If you use a perceptron on a multi-label task, you gain nothing, as it doesn't bind the two labels. You can use a structured perceptron and learn the interactions between the two labels using PyStruct http://pystruct.github.io/auto_examples/multi_label.html , if that is what you are looking for.